# Why is the projection operator equal to $P_{H_k} x = \sum_{j=1}^k \langle x, e_j \rangle e_j$?

Tags: operator-theory, projection

Let $H_k = \text{span }\left\{ e_1, ..., e_k \right\}$ and $H_k$ is a closed subspace of Hilbert Space H.

We define the projection: $$P_{H_k} x = \sum_{j=1}^k \langle x, e_j \rangle e_j$$

But why exactly? Is there maybe a geometrical proof (with the help of Pythagorean Theorem)? I especially don't understand from where $\langle x, e_j \rangle$ is coming from

Comment: Geometrically - you project onto an orthonormal set by projecting individually onto each of it's components/basis vectors. The inner product represent these individual projections.

Comment: Should you also be stating that $\{e_1, ..., e_k\}$ is orthonormal?

Comment: Let $H = \mathbb R^3$ and $H_2 = \operatorname{span}\{e_1,e_2\}$, where the $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors. What is $P_{H_2}x$ then?

Comment: @rubikscube09 But why does the inner product represent these individual projections?

Comment: @amsmath Definitely it should be such, that $\langle P_{H_2} x , e_1 \rangle = \langle P_{H_2} x , e_2 \rangle = 0$

Comment: @anon No, definitely not. However, if $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$, please compute $P_{H_2}x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i e_i$ is the projection of some $x$ onto $H_k$. Then, $x - \sum_{i=1}^k a_i e_i$ is perpendicular to $H_k$, and in particular, each $e_i$. We can write:
$$x = \left(x - \sum_{i=1}^k a_i e_i\right) + \sum_{i=1}^ka_i e_i. \tag{$\star$}$$
Now, take the inner product of each side of $(\star)$ with respect to $e_j$. Then,
\begin{align*}
\langle x, e_j \rangle &= \left\langle x - \sum_{i=1}^k a_i e_i, e_j\right\rangle + \sum_{i=1}^k\langle a_i e_i, e_j\rangle \\
&= 0 + \sum_{i=1}^k a_i \langle e_i, e_j \rangle = a_j.
\end{align*}
If we replace this formula for $a_j$ into the sum $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i e_i$, we obtain precisely the projection formula from the question.

Note also that, if we have a finite-dimensional Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $(e_1, \ldots, e_n)$, and we "project" a vector $x$ onto the entire space, then we should get $x$ back, leading to the helpful formula:
$$x = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle x, e_i \rangle e_i.$$